Kotlin Duration to ISO8601 String
I'm trying to convert Kotlin Duration to String formed ISO8601.
First, I implemented like below:
val duration: Duration = 2970.toDuration(DurationUnit.MINUTES)
val isoString: String = duration.toIsoString()
println(isoString)

and then, the code return the string:
PT49H30M

I expected the returned string would look like P2DT1H30M, but the default form of .toIsoString() is under time H.
Although I can handle this problem like below:
val duration: Duration = 2970.toDuration(DurationUnit.MINUTES)
val isoString = duration.toComponents({days, hours, minutes, seconds, _ ->
        if (days == 0L && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            "P0D"
        } else {
            "P" +
                    (if (days > 0) "${days}D" else "") +
                    (if (hours > 0) "T${hours}H" else "") +
                    (if (minutes > 0) "${if (hours == 0) "T" else ""}${minutes}M" else "") +
                    (if (seconds > 0) "${if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0) "T" else ""}${seconds}S" else "")
        }
    })
println(isoString) // P2DT1H30M

but I wonder if there are any library-level functions.
Thanks a lot in advance for kind answers!

It's ok with anything(not only Duration) which is converted to ISO8601 string with DAY.
I've read kotlin duration documents but I cannnot find any satisfactory good solutions

If you are open to using other libraries, then this could be a duplicate target. It's often a bad idea to represent both periods and durations at the same time.. Why are you trying to do this? Might be an XY Problem.

Kotlin's Duration mimics Java's Duration, whose toString() method says: "Note that multiples of 24 hours are not output as days to avoid confusion with Period", which is explained further in the answer linked by @Sweeper
